# Is it possible to iterate my object name in jQuery.each?

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I've used some code to loop through 42 times and create 3 empty objects per loop.

```
jQuery.each(vote_cat_array, function(index, value) { 
    window['vote_cat_'+value+'_default_values_left'] = {};
    window['vote_cat_'+value+'_default_values_middle'] = {};
    window['vote_cat_'+value+'_default_values_right'] = {};
});
```

Later on in my code, I am pushing data into each object and then further down, I am retreiving the data from each object for use elsewhere on my page.

Here is that code as it stands right now:

```
jQuery('.reset').on('click', function(){

    var reset_selector = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    if(reset_selector == 'vote_cat_1'){
        jQuery.each(vote_cat_1_default_values_left, function(key, value) {   
            jQuery('.'+reset_selector+'.gf_left_third select').append(jQuery("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value)); 
        });
    }

    if(reset_selector == 'vote_cat_2'){
        jQuery.each(vote_cat_2_default_values_left, function(key, value) {   
            jQuery('.'+reset_selector+'.gf_left_third select').append(jQuery("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value)); 
        });
    }

});
```

I'd rather not have to include that code 42 times manually, for each numeric iteration, so I am wondering if there is a way to just have the code once and iterate the number in the object name through some kind of loop?

I've done some research and I'm not sure whether its possible or not so I figured I would ask here rather than wasting any more time trying to figure out if its even possible.

I just need to automatically iterate the number in the object name so that it runs through a loop so I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
jQuery('.reset').on('click', function(){

    var reset_selector = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    jQuery.each(vote_cat_+iteration+_default_values_left, function(key, value) {   
        jQuery('.'+reset_selector+'.gf_left_third select').append(jQuery("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value)); 
    });
});
```

Or even:

```
jQuery('.reset').on('click', function(){

    var reset_selector = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    jQuery.each(reset_selector+'_default_values_left', function(key, value) {   
        jQuery('.'+reset_selector+'.gf_left_third select').append(jQuery("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value)); 
    });
});
```

Is something like this possible or do I just have to do it manually?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Uh, `vote_cat_1_default_values_left` == `window['vote_cat_1_default_values_left']` so, you can just use brackets access. However, I'm not sure why you add these to `window` at all as global variables. Why not just add them to an object, so you can more easily access them?

Comment: As VLAZ suggested, I wouldn't use global variables and use properties of the element (select?) to store the default values.  Use the reset control in relation to the select (Same parent?) to find the select that is to be "reset", then pull the data from one of it's properties that you have stuffed with the values... Or a string that represents the innerHtml.  A better answer would require knowing more about the flow of your document however.

Comment: It might be easier if we had the bigger picture of just what it was you were trying to accomplish. There is likely an easier way of doing this than with what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I think I've solved my specific issue. I'll post my final solution in a bit once I'm certain its working.